# JPA ManyToMany fields

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb, ejb-3.0, seam

I use seam framework and JPA.
I have an entity permission that contain(id_permission, action_permission, discriminator_permission)
and an entity role that contain (id_role, name_role)

I use the bidirectional association ManyToMany between these two entities that generate a join table AccountPermission that contain(id_permission,id_role,name_role,action_permission,discriminator_permission)

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="AccountPermission",
           joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="role_id",
                                    referencedColumnName="role_id"),
                        @JoinColumn(name="name_role",
                                    referencedColumnName="name_role"),},
           inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="action_permission",
                                 referencedColumnName="action_permission"),
                               @JoinColumn(name="discriminator_permission",
                                 referencedColumnName="discriminator_permission"),
                               @JoinColumn(name="permission_id",
                                 referencedColumnName="permission_id")})

public List<Permission> getPermissions() {
    return permissions; 
}   

public void setPermissions(List<Permission> permissions) {
    this.permissions = permissions; 
}
```

So, as you see all the attribute affected in the join table are from the two table.
My problem is on the attribute "name_role" that I don't want to have a joint with it because it's an editable attribute. so how can I persist these value on the join table without making join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the primary key of those two tables. I guess id_role is the primary key for role, and id_permission is the primary key for permission.

If so, the join table should only contain the IDs of both tables:

```
@ManyToMany   
@JoinTable(name = "AccountPermission",
           joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id")}
           inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="permission_id"})
public List<Permission> getPermissions()
```

Comment: yes, role_id and permission_id are the two primary key for role and permission but i need when i persist the role the join table accountpermission will contain role_id and permission_id and also role_name and permission_action

Comment: Learn about database normalization. There is no reason to put this information in the join table, since the join table has a foreign key to the role (which alread contains the role_name), and another foreign key to the permission (which already contains the permission_action).

Comment: yes i know that... but the problem is when i use the jpapermissionstore with seam i need to have permission_action and role_name stored at the table accountpermission

Comment: I don't know about Seam, but you must make something wrong, because Seam is built with JPA in mind, has been initiated by Gavin King who also designed Hibernate, and you should not pollute your database model to make Seam happy.

Comment: lol, yes sure.. that's why i will not use the jpapermissionstore api of seam and i will implement my own method that use the correct model that contain only the two id of both table.